# Swift: C++ friend Equivalent?

Tags: swift, class, encapsulation, friend, class-structure

I have a structure similar to the following:

```
class Foo{
    class Bar{ ... }
    private class Baz{ ... } 
}
```

`Foo` and `Bar` need access to `Baz`, but `Baz` needs to remain private to both the module and and other modules importing it.

**Questions:**

1. Is there any way to share `Baz` to `Foo` and `Bar`?'
2. Is there any other class structure that I could use that would allow the wanted access?

Comment: How about `fileprivate` for `Baz`?

Comment: @imike I have never heard of `fileprivate`. Thanks! You could post your comment as an answer...

Comment: To be honest, `friend` Is pretty discouraged in C++ to begin with. It just adds complexity and rigidity without much “real benefit”

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to nest the classes to achieve this.

```
class Foo {
    // entire module can access
}

class Bar {
    // entire module can access
}

private class Baz {
    // only objects in this file can access
}
```

If, however, you want to nest the types then you can make use of `fileprivate`.

```
class Foo {
    class Bar {}
    fileprivate class Baz {}
}
```